# How to find out Hosting KVM Server IP address from Virtual Machine

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have got large number of virtual machines running on 3 KVM servers.I would like to identify the host's server IP address/hostname from a guest machine.

Comment: I doubt this is possible

Answer (score 1):

How is your network configured?

If your guests are connected in bridging mode, then it is not possible. The host machine does not even have to have an IP address configured on the bridging interface.

If you are using NAT, then your virtual host is the gateway of the guest.